# ActiveRecord: Check Number of Database Calls

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

For demo purposes, suppose that I have a class called `DemoThing` with a method called `do_something`.

Is there a way that (in code) I can check the number of times that `do_something` hits the database? Is there a way that I can "spy" on active record to count the number of times that the database was called?

For instance:

```
class DemoThing

  def do_something
     retVal = []
     5.times do |i|
       retVal << MyActiveRecordModel.where(:id => i)
     end

     retVal
  end

end

dt = DemoThing.new
stuff = dt.do_something # want to assert that do_something hit the database 5 times
```

Comment: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_support_instrumentation.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ActiveRecord should be logging each query in STDOUT.

But for the above code, it's pretty obvious that you're making 5 calls for each iteration of `i`.

Queries can be made more efficient by not mixing Ruby logic with querying.

In this example, gettings the ids before querying will mean that the query isn't called for each Ruby loop.

```
ids = 5.times.to_a
retVal = MyActiveRecordModel.where(id: ids) # .to_a if retVal needs to be an Array
```

Answer (score 0):

Sure is.  But first you must understand Rails' Query Cache and logger.  By default, Rails will attempt to optimize performance by turning on a simple query cache.  It is a hash stored on the current thread (one for every active database connection - Most rails processes will have just one ).  Whenever a select statement is made (like find or where etc.), the corresponding result set is stored in a hash with the SQL that was used to query them as the key.  You'll notice when you run the above method your log will show `Model Load` statement and then a `CACHE` statement.  Your database was only queried one time, with the other 4 being loaded via cache.  Watch your server logs as you run that query.

Answer (score -1):

I found a gem for queries count https://github.com/comboy/sql_queries_count